# Get Json value with Hierarchies and Put on in a Variable

Tags: json, vb.net, youtube-api, label

I'm trying to get the number of subscribers from a channel using the Youtube API. But this api contains some levels of hierarchy before reaching the value and using the code I know can only get up to 2 levels. How do I get this value and put it in a variable and then put it in a label, my code is not working.

**NOTE:** I'm using Newtonsoft.Json

**API Link**

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=UCuxfOdbKQy0tgGXcm9sjHiw&fields=items(statistics(subscriberCount))&key=AIzaSyA1n4M-fo2Y5NHUj0RsvXEAis3H6_lIjRg
```

**Json**

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "statistics": {
    "subscriberCount": "7484439"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

**Code**

```
    Dim ChannelID As String = "UCuxfOdbKQy0tgGXcm9sjHiw"
    Dim Subs As String

    Dim json = New IO.StreamReader(DirectCast(DirectCast(Net.WebRequest.Create("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=" & ChannelID & "&fields=items(statistics(subscriberCount))&key=AIzaSyA1n4M-fo2Y5NHUj0RsvXEAis3H6_lIjRg"), Net.HttpWebRequest).GetResponse, Net.HttpWebResponse).GetResponseStream)
    Dim rq As Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json.ReadToEnd)

    Subs = $"{rq.SelectToken("items")("statistics")("subscriberCount")}"

    Label1.Text = Subs
```

Comment: I updated the publication, take a look.

Comment: I've already tried this, it always returns this error: https://i.imgur.com/c2j1oU4.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
Subs = $"{rq.SelectToken("items")("statistics")("subscriberCount")}"
```

should be

```
Subs = $"{rq.SelectToken("items")(0)("statistics")("subscriberCount")}"
```